# Get value of specific $_POST array

Tags: php

```
name="qty<?php echo $key?>"



foreach ($_POST as $items => $value)
{
  // check qty >1???
echo $key, ' => ', $value, '<br />';
}
```

How do I show only items which their values of [qty1]=>value,[qty2]=>value...  >0  ?

Comment: Let me introduce you to [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

Comment: You mean `if($key =='qt1')`?

Comment: `if($value > 1) do something...`

Comment: $value includes model1=>value, msrp1=>value, qty1=>value....
How do we only access $value of qty1=>value, qty2=>value...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a check in your loop and then get a filtered output like this:

if your POST request is not a **multidimensional** array then use this:

```
$output = array_filter($_POST, function ($value, $key) {
        // check your keys start with 'qty' and its value is greater than one
        return strpos($key, 'qty') === 0 && $value > 1; 
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

// display final output
print_r($output);
```

If your POST request is a **multidimensional** array then use this:

```
$output = array(); // declare a blank array to store filtered output

foreach($_POST as $row)
    {
    if (is_array($row))
        {

        // this code is because qty is dynamic and we need to check it for all.

        foreach($row as $key => $value)
            {
            if ("qty" == substr($key, 0, 3) && $value > 0)
                {
                $output[] = $row;
                }
            }
        }
    }

// display final array.

print_r($output);
```

Hope that will help!

Comment: There are about 200 items . How do we check all of them then show items with qty1,qty2,qty3... >0 only ?

Comment: What do you mean? you have multiple qty values in array and you want to them all for > 0?

Comment: I mean only show items which their values of qty >0 ?

Comment: @Steve check my code now. This will find all keys for a row and check them for > 0. $row will go in $output only if its qty value is > 0. Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: The output is Array() . Nothing bro

Comment: Check this code. I have taken an example of **POST Request**. Check here: [Working Code](https://pastebin.com/GgWhhpWd)

Comment: I don't think his post request is a multidimensional array. The inner loop by itself would probably work.

Comment: @Mikey haha.. if he doesn't have his POST request multidimensional then it would be an easiest question to answer :D

Comment: It is the easiest question to answer :D

Comment: I think it didn't work with my $_POST array ? here is my print_r($_POST) output:
[model1] => FSE 60 [msrp1] => 129.95 [qty1] => 3 [rule1] => RPO [discount1] => 0 [model2] => FS 38 [msrp2] => 129.95 [qty2] => 2 [rule2] => RPO [discount2] => 0 [model3] => FS 40 C-E [msrp3] => 159.95 [qty3] => [rule3] => RPO [discount3] => 0 [model4] => FS 50 C-E [msrp4] => 199.95 [qty4] => [rule4] => RPO [discount4] => 0

Comment: @Steve: Check my answer for not a multidimensional array. That will surely help you. These both solutions work very well.

Comment: Not Multi array worked but yeah only shows 1 array of qty, another solution didn't work it showed empty Array()

Comment: @Steve So, did you get your answer now? Still problem with code?

Comment: @Steve: Another solution is working if POST is multidimensional array. I tested that on [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) and that worked like a charm.

Comment: Your multi array code didn't work. Still show Array () :(

Comment: Lets discuss this in chat. You might be getting different POST request.

Comment: Got error when moving to chat, is there any way you can see my codes? Thanks alot

Comment: Add me on Google Hangouts with email: sat1234ish[at]gmail[dot]com

Answer (score 1):

Just use combination of [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

```
$_POST = [
   'notme' => 12,
   'qty1' => 1,
   'qty2' => 20,
   'qty3' => -1,
   'qty4' => 0,
   'qty5' => 30
];

print_r(
    array_filter($_POST, function ($value, $key) {
        // check key starts with 'qty' and its value is greater than one
        return strpos($key, 'qty') === 0 && $value > 1; 
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)
);

// Array ( [qty2] => 20 [qty5] => 30 )
```